# Blockquoted Spoilers with Code

Tags: bug

There seems to be a problem with blockquoted spoilers that contain code blocks. You can see an example [in this answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/15342/5033). Here's how it shows in my browser (Chrome 43):

[image]

You can clearly see the text even though it is supposed to be a spoiler.

Sometimes, answers require a visual text representation, and the code formatting works best because it is the only way to force a monospaced font.

This also only seems to be a problem on the puzzling.so site, and not on meta or other SO sites.

Please fix the CSS to accurately retain the spoilers.

Comment: @mmking The spoiler text is not hidden. Maybe it's browser specific, but I've included an image of how it shows on mine.

Comment: Oh, you're right. I didn't see because the words are so faint.

Comment: This is a known issue with a workaround: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/245142/202205

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an easy workaround to this, which is to use inline code formatting on each word, rather than a `<pre>` block.

Thus this (note that there are double spaces at the end of each line -- `<br>` also works):

```
>!`ZEBUS`  
>!`EARNT`  
>!`BRIDE`  
>!`UNDUE`
>!`STEED`
```

renders as intended:

> `ZEBUS`
> `EARNT`
> `BRIDE`
> `UNDUE`
> `STEED`

Unfortunate, because it's semantically incorrect...